# Counting/Print Unique Words in Directory up to x instances

Tags: python, sorting, while-loop, directory

I am attempting to take all unique words in tale4653, count their instances, and then read off the top 100 mentioned unique words.

My struggle is sorting the directory so that I can print both the unique word and its' respected instances.

### My code thus far:

```
import string 

fhand = open('tale4653.txt')

counts = dict()

for line in fhand:

    line = line.translate(None, string.punctuation)

    line = line.lower()

    words = line.split()

    for word in words:

        if word not in counts:

            counts[word] = 1

        else:

            counts[word] += 1

fhand.close()

rangedValue = sorted(counts.values(), reverse=True)

i =0 

while i<100:

    print rangedValue[i]

    i=i+1
```

Thank you community,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [top values from dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902665/top-values-from-dictionary)

Comment: A dict cannot be sorted. But you can convert your dict to a list of tuples `(count, word)` which can easily be.

Comment: As an aside ... For constructing your dictionary, you might find [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) helpful.

Comment: I was unfamiliar with tuples prior this, but began experimenting with them! Thank you all for the assistance, I ended up creating a second dictionary of tuples which read the tuple value, then key!

Answer (score 0):

you loose the word (the key in your dictionary) when you do `counts.values()`)

you can do this instead

```
rangedValue = sorted(counts.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
for word, count in rangedValue:
    print word + ': ' + str(rangedValue)
```

when you do counts.items() it will return a list of tuples of key and value like this:

```
[('the', 1), ('end', 2)]
```

and when we sort it we tell it to take the second value as the "key" to sort with

Answer (score 0):

DorElias is correct in the initial problem: you need to use `count.items()` with `key=lambda x: x[1]` or `key=operator.itemgetter(1)`, latter of which would be faster.

---

However, I'd like to show how I'd do it, completely avoiding `sorted` in your code. `collections.Counter` is an optimal data structure for this code. I also prefer the logic of reading words in a file be wrapped in a generator

```
import string 
from collections import Counter

def read_words(filename):
    with open(filename) as fhand:
        for line in fhand:
            line = line.translate(None, string.punctuation)
            line = line.lower()
            words = line.split()
            for word in words: # in Python 3 one can use `yield from words`
                yield word        

counts = Counter(read_words('tale4653.txt'))
for word, count in counts.most_common(100):
    print('{}: {}'.format(word, count))
```