# Filtering information from Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a function:

```
def most_common(dictionary, integer):
```

'Integer' must be a positive number.  This function must update the list to include the 'Integer' most common words in the dictionary.

For example

```
>>> def most_common({'ONE': 1, 'TWO': 2, 'THREE': 3}, 2)
>>> {'TWO' : 2, 'THREE' : 3}
```

The only code I have written for this function so far is to sort the dictionary.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: want you to count most popular integer in the list i.e. list elements order by desc?

Comment: @SheepPerplexed your behaviour is just exemplary. Keep it like this! one small advice on your future answers though: test them, and provide an explanation around them, they'll be better recieved than code-only answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the most common words, use `collections.Counter` and its `most_common` method:

```
>>> import collections
>>> L = {'One' : 1, 'Two' : 2, 'Three' : 3}
>>> result = collections.Counter(L)
>>> dict(result.most_common(2)
{'Two': 2, 'Three': 3}
```

Comment: `dict(result.most_common(2))` seems a little neater IMO

Comment: @Chris_Rands - Neat!

Comment: Hi thank you for your responses.  I cannot use the `collections.Counter` unfortunately.  I cannot import anything must use more basic python.  Do you think you can still help?

Comment: @dontworry123 use `lambda` and see my tests below!

Comment: @dontworry123 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40953104/758836

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(sorted([(k,v) for k, v in L.items()], key=lambda x: x[1])[-2:])
```